# Google Script - Internal Error after 15 seconds

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am writing a script that we give the sum of all the data that has a specific tag in the same row.

```
Col 1  |  Col 2
-------+---------
grp1   |   2
grp1   |   1 
grp2   |   1
-------+---------
```

If I was to pass this function grp1 the result would be 3.

When I use this script over 1000 rows, I get an error "Internal Error Executing the custom function" after a short time (like 15 seconds). I thought it might be the timeout but it happens well before 30 seconds. Any ideas?

```
function collectgrpdata(group, startrow) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var currentcell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var col = currentcell.getColumn();
  var total = 0;

  for(var x = startrow;  x <= lastrow; x++) {
    var v = sheet.getRange(x, col).getValue();
    if(v != "" ) { 
      if (sheet.getRange(x, 2).getValue() == group) {
           total += v;
      }    
    }
  }
  return total
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely due to the fact that you do so many calls to getRange and getValue.
You are probably hitting your [quota limit of calls](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

instead of doing that do one big call to get all the data and then work with that:

```
function collectgrpdata2(group, startrow) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var currentcell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var col = currentcell.getColumn();
  var range = sheet
      .getRange(startrow, 
                col, 
                sheet.getLastRow() - startrow + 1, 
                sheet.getLastColumn() - col + 1)

  var data = range.getValues();

  return data
      .filter(function(row) {return row[0] === group;})
      .map(function(row) {return row[1];})
      .concat(0)
      .reduce(function(x,y) {return x+y;});
}
```